# Angular 6 'app-action-button' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular, module

i am trying to add component shared between modules. Only thing i am getting is this error.

I was searching for answer on similiar questions, but it did not help and i am constantly getting this error.

Tried to declare it in app.module too, but it results with same error.

Code:

**Component**

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-action-button',
    templateUrl: './action-button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./action-button.component.scss'],
})

export class ActionButtonComponent {

    private _className = '';
    private _buttonText = '';

    @Input()
    set className(className: string) {
        this._className = (className && className.trim() || 'default');
    }
    get className(): string { return this._className; }

    @Input()
    set buttonText(buttonText: string) {
        this._buttonText = (buttonText && buttonText.trim() || 'n/n');
    }
    get buttonText(): string { return this._buttonText; }

    @Output() buttonActionEvent = new EventEmitter();


    constructor() { }

    buttonAction() {
        this.buttonActionEvent.emit(true);
    }
}
```

**Module where i am declaring this component**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../material.module';
import { ActionButtonComponent } from '../../shared/action-button/action-button.component';
import { ActionButtonModule } from '../../shared/action-button/action-button.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule, ActionButtonModule],
    declarations: [LoginComponent],
    entryComponents: [ActionButtonComponent],
    providers: [LoginService]
})

export class LoginModule {}
```

**html template**

```
    <div class="login-wrapper">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isLoading">
        <mat-spinner class="loading" diameter="32"></mat-spinner>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
        <h2>Zaloguj się za pomocą czytnika</h2>
        <form [formGroup]="operator">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>ID Operatora *</mat-label>
                <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Zeskanuj kod kreskowy" formControlName="id">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Wybór maszyny *</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="machine">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let machine of machinesList" [value]="machine.externalId">
                        {{ machine.name }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </form>
        <!-- <div class="buttons-wrapper">
            <button (click)="getUrl()" mat-raised-button>maszyna Bullmer</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary">maszyna nieBullmer</button>
        </div> -->
        <app-action-button [className]="logout-button" (buttonActionEvent)="test()"></app-action-button>
        <button [disabled]="!operator.valid" (click)="loginAndSetMachine()" mat-raised-button>
            <mat-icon color="primary" fontSet="fas" fontIcon="fa-check" class="material-icons"></mat-icon>
        </button>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

@Edit
I made ActionButton module and imported it in LoginModule. Still getting same error.

**ActionButton module**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../material.module';

import { ActionButtonComponent } from './action-button.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule],
    declarations: [ActionButtonComponent],
    exports : [ActionButtonComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: []
})

export class ActionButtonModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share it between modules, you have to add it to the exports of the module where you declare it and import that module to the module where you want to use your `ActionButtonComponent`.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule],
    declarations: [LoginComponent, ActionButtonComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: [LoginService],
    exports:[ActionButtonComponent]
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

### Your other module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...,LoginModule],
    declarations: [],
    exports:[]
})
export class OtherModule {}
```

Now you can use `ActionButtonComponent` in any component which is declared in `OtherModule`

Comment: It didn't help, still getting same error and i updated my question.

Comment: have you tried stopping ng serve, and start it again?

Comment: have you checked if there is another template file where you use the component and forgot to import your new module?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that `ActionButtonComponent` is exported by it's module. After exporting, you can import this `LoginModule` anywhere and use the component:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule],
    declarations: [LoginComponent, ActionButtonComponent],
    exports: [ActionButtonComponent],  // This exports the shared component
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: [LoginService]
})

export class LoginModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in other template file i tried to use this component declaration...